# Setting background colour for a cell in Rstudio gt package

Tags: r, colors, cut

Using the *data_color* function in the **gt** package, I'd like to set up custom colors for a continuous distribution using non-equal ranges. *cut()* organizes the data correctly (outside of gt), but when using *scale::col_bins()* as an argument to *data_color()*, my code fails, producing no colours:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
diamonds %>% select(color, price) %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(meanprice=mean(price))-> junk

junk$cutprice <- cut(junk$meanprice, breaks=c(3000, 3500, 4000,     5000, 10000), labels=FALSE)


junk %>% select(-cutprice) %>%  gt() %>% 
      data_color(columns=var(meanprice),
                 color=scales::col_bin(
                    bins=c(3000, 3500, 4000, 5000, 10000),
                    palette = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "black"),
                    domain=c(2000, 8000))
        )
```

The initial use of base::cut() works fine, but my syntax for the col_bin argument to data color is clearly failing. Suggestions on alternative syntax. I could not find an example of scale::col_bins() to address this situation.

Many thanks,

Comment: This is just a typo I think, it should be `columns=vars(meanprice)`. Unfortunately `var(meanprice)` returns an integer, which is a valid input to `columns`, making it harder to spot the error.

Comment: Yes. Works perfectly.

Comment: library(tidyverse)
library(gt)


diamonds %>% select(color, price) %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(meanprice=mean(price))-> junk

junk$cutprice <- cut(junk$meanprice, breaks=c(3000, 3500, 4000, 5000, 10000), labels=FALSE)

glimpse(junk)

head(junk)
junk %>% select(-cutprice) %>%  gt() %>% 
  data_color(columns=vars(meanprice),
             color=scales::col_bin(
               bins=c(2000, 3500, 4000, 5000, 8000),
               palette = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"),
               domain=c(2000, 8000))
  )

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
diamonds %>% select(color, price) %>% group_by(color) %>% summarise(meanprice=mean(price))-> junk

junk$cutprice <- cut(junk$meanprice, breaks=c(3000, 3500, 4000,     5000, 10000), labels=FALSE)


junk %>% select(-cutprice) %>%  gt() %>% 
  data_color(columns=vars(meanprice), ### Changed 'var' to 'vars'
             color=scales::col_bin(
               bins=c(3000, 3500, 4000, 5000, 10000),
               palette = c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "black"),
               domain=c(2000, 8000))
  )
```